# I want to know how and where can I use "cerr" in c++?

Tags: c++

I want to know how and where can I use "cerr" in c++?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error_stream#Standard_error_.28stderr.29

Answer (score 2):

Everywhere you

1. `#include <iostream>` and
2. use the `std::` namespace

Answer (score 1):

The conventional stream to send errors through. [cerr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cerr/).

Also, [Shall I use cerr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058716/shall-i-use-cerr)

Answer (score 0):

`cerr` is used to pass strings to the error stream. It is different from cout, which is the output stream.

For example, you can do the following:

```
cerr << "Hello world!" << endl;
```

By default, this directed to the terminal in the same way that cout is. However, it is useful if you want to redirect your errors to a different place than your output. For example, you may want to run a program and log all unexpected events or errors in a separate file, so that the user only sees the output that is meant for the user.

Alternatively, you may want to see **only** the errors (e.g. instead of using `cout`statements to debug a program that already has a lot of output, you can use `cerr`to print statements that denote that some error has occurred).